Color 80s/90s horror, maybe Hellraiser(?). Labyrinth and hell
I'm really not sure and don't want to try each part of Hellraiser to find it, but maybe someone would tell me what movies was that:

There was huge labyrinth which had to be traversed to go to some place visible on the horizon (but not as in Leviathan, not these actors).
The film was constantly dark and navy blue (maybe this was the TV or channel).
The film was from 80s or 90s as it was seen by me about 90s. Color movie.
There were some monsters. Maybe only one but important and seen on the screen from time to time.
As I remember the most parts of the film were in hell (seems like Hellraiser, but which part?).
There were some young men and women as the main actors (still Hellraiser).
It was horror.
I don't remember guy with needles on his head, so it would not be Hellraiser (it can be other film).

EDIT:

It was one movie, not series. At most 2-3 parts but not a series.
These were current (90s) times in the movie, not any past before.


Can you explain what you mean by 'not as in Leviathan'?

Walt: I've seen that part on YT and it is not that dark there. It looks very similar. @MrLore Yes, it is familiar, but the maze was flat and it was dark.

@pbies: What part? Number 2?

@Walt http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u2qT7GylRxw 0:27

Right, so not HII then. And it would be too silly to suggest Labyrinth, right? ;)

@Walt HII was the first shot and I'll try it, but Labyrinth from which year, 1986? Seems to bo not the one I am looking for. It was not a movie for children. And there was no David Bowie.

FWIW, there are other characters in the maze in HII: the daughter from the first movie and a young girl, IIRC. The full movie is currently on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9FLDNJkVOM

Yes, I've found it, I mean HII on YT, but: there is too young girl, there are no 17-25 few boys and girls, there is no view on the maze from about 100m above. I remember now, that the toy which the girl had was in this movie. Maybe one of the next parts? But which? The movie was made better than HII, so it should be a little newer.

As far as I know, there are no giant mazes in the other sequels... Sorry. If you remember anything else, please edit the question and add it in.

It was Time Bandits.

Here is the scene with the maze:



You're TV was broken. Though it does have many dark scenes.
Released 1981. Color.
Not the gross kind of monsters we think today, but they call them monsters in the trailer. Giants, a Minotaur, etc.
It wasn't in 'hell', but many parts took place in Evil's lair. It is more surreal.
Contains young men & women (Shelly Duval), even a young boy.
I wouldn't call it horror, but some scenes did scare me when I was little.
No needle guy.


No, not this movie.

+1 for thinking of Time Bandits. Loved that movie. The bad guy was a wizard of some type and looked like a monster. There were other monsters are well.
